# Using AJAX in monodevelop

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, mono

So I have been searching the web extensively for how to use the AJAX toolkit in mono ASP.
so far what I have gathered is that you need to add System.Web.Extensions
to your references. But for some odd reason I cannot use it in my WebForms site
`<asp:ScriptManager>` simply doesn't exists so can someone tell me what I have missed?
I'm using mono version 3.0.4.6

Answer (score 0):

you need System.Web.Extensions if you like combine ajax calls and callbacks. But you don't need it if you use jQuery instead of ajax toolkit.

And monodevelop is only for edit the aspx or the js files and run xsp to do the test.

XSP will respond ok to the jquery calls

Comment: that is exactly what I am looking for. combining ajax calls and server callbacks.

Let me specify a bit, i have en asp:listbox that does a postback when something is selected, it then communicates with the server and gets some info. so when ever people are pressing that button the whole site is refreshed, Which is something i would avoid.

so what I would want is to embed that into an ajax call so only partial site is updated, hence the scriptmanager and then updatetable

I'm not really interrested in doing this with jQuery as I have seen that it is possible with asp .net